# Is it possible to amalgamate analytics from Facebook, Instagram, et cetera into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I would like to have a single source of truth for my company's analytics tracking.

The company is a start-up Martial Arts Online Academy focusing (now) on exercise-at-home.

Currently I've set up Google Analytics. This will integrate with Google Ads, the WordPress site, and the course content on Teachable.

As we launch advertising campaigns, we will wish to track analytics from Facebook, Instagram, pinterest, etc.

Is Analytics Amalgamation a thing? Is it possible to direct all analytics into GA? Is this a sensible goal to pursue?

Can anyone offer pointers/resources to get started on this?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to use custom campaign tagging (or auto tagging on the platforms that support it - such as Bing and Facebook). This can be combined with uploading click and cost data from the non google platforms, which will enable you to compare it against Google Ads data in GA.

More info on uploading cost data can be found in the GA help docs:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2803329?hl=en